# Weekly reports with confluence

Tags: reporting, status, confluence

We've got confluence and it's all good and stuff. Can't figure out one thing though. Say I have a page for a project and want it to have a subpage for weekly status reporting - a simple table with week start date, what's been done, what's not be done and issues and problems.

Ideally, I want them guys to be able to get onto this page and click "post a report" button and fill out a form to do this. There is page templates in confluence but I can't figure out how to orginize what I need. There might be other proper practices for confluence in this regard - I will appreciate any suggestions.

*They can edit the page and copy-paste the report table and change the wording but I sort of want it to be little more friendly than that.*

We don't own the installation so getting new plugins is possible but going deeper is not what I'm targeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [confluence page templates](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Creating+a+Page+using+a+Template) as the way to go.
You can get around the 'create page' screen by using the [Create Page Plugin](https://www.adaptavist.com/display/Plugins/Create+Page) from Adaptavist. In both cases you need to provide a template though.